# Editing Changed works in IOS5 but not IOS6. textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange:

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, xcode4.5

I have a textfield that runs a calculation and updates a label when Editing Changed.  The textfield is formated for currency using textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange:

The label is also formatted for currency.

In IOS 5 the label would update as the number was typed into the textfield.

In IOS 6 the label won't update until a value is entered in a different textfield.

Has anything changed in IOS 6 or Xcode 4.5 to make Editing Changed or textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange: work differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I justs noticed the same thing - make note that only if shouldChangeCharactersInRange returns "NO" will editingChanged not get called - even so I suspect that this is a bug and should be reported to Apple. The EditingChanged event is just an event in which UITexField inherits from UIControl and I don't see why Apple should stop it from working even if shouldChangeCharactersInRange returns "NO" the textfield should know if there was a change made.

What I am doing is moving my code from the editingChanged event directly into the shouldChangeCharactersInRange method. Meaning, that where I return "NO" I am embedding the code I would have wanted to call in the editingChanged event. Should work for most cases. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for figuring what's causing this.  I hope I can find a fix other than moving the code though.  That would be a ton of work for me on this app.

Comment: Another idea which I have not tested yet could be - posting a notification from within the shouldChangeCharactersInRange method that the textfield's text has changed and then trigger the editingChanged method by observing for that notification . . .

Comment: Posting a notification in the shouldChangeCharactersInRange to trigger my method worked.  Thanks again for the help!!